# Enable/disable all breakpoints without affecting each breakpoint state

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-debugging

In Visual Studio, is there any way to disable all breakpoints without affecting their actual state, like in XCode.

Or does Visual Studio has something like *breakpoint configuration* to easily switch between breakpoints sets?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Here it is: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2010/04/27/enable-or-disable-all-breakpoints-vstipdebug0018.aspx

As for breakpoint configurations, sort of: look at Labels in the Breakpoints Window.

Comment: Ok. Here is commonly used scenario by steps: 
1) 2 breakpoints enabled + 1 disabled, 
2) Debug->Disable All Breakpoints (I test program without any breakpoints)
3) After testing found some wrong in my code - need breakpoints back (2 breakpoints enabled + 1 disabled)
4) Debug->Enable All Breakpoints (And now all breakpoints are enabled - it is not that I need)

Comment: Therefore I have not found solution yet!